# PostgreSQL dynamically SELECT last json array value

Tags: json, postgresql

How do I dynamically `SELECT` the last array value in a JSON type column in PostgreSQL?

```
id: 2927
material_size: [".016 x 1.156","0","1"]
```

I could statically retrieve the last value "1" using:

```
 SELECT material_size->>2 AS material_size FROM table_name;
```

However that would always get the second record instead of the *last* record (if the number of values isn't exactly three).

Comment: To be precise: ` material_size->>2 ` would get the *third element*, not the ` second record `.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the JSON array and use that (minus one) as the index:

```
with t1 as (select 2927 id, '[".016 x 1.156","0","1"]'::json material_size)
select material_size->>(json_array_length(material_size)-1) from t1;
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html.

Comment: ... why are you presuming I have data from the database *before* I've made the query?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... are you referring to the CTE? That was just for demonstration purposes (to make this a [self-contained example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)). And the solution itself is just reusing the `material_size` column, so it's not pulling/using data that isn't received from the query...

Comment: Okay; I'll have to come back to this soon to verify and accept, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **negative index** to query elements in a JSON value from the end:

```
 SELECT material_size->>-1 AS material_size FROM table_name;
```